# VMWare ESXi in memory database shared across VMs on a single blade

Tags: vmware, shared-memory, virtualization, esxi

probably a stupid question (sorry!) but within VMWare ESXi, is there any way I can share memory across VMs on the same blade such that two VMs can perform interprocess communication through the shared memory block rather than using messaging? I know I can share memory across VMs but it's the interprocess communication I'm interested in. The aim would be that the two VMs can access an in memory db really quickly but (unlike a hosted OS solution) if a VM went down, the other VM could still merrily keep going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the vSockets API documentation, it says:

> "The original VMCI library was released as an experimental C language interface with Workstation 6.0. VMCI included a datagram API and a shared memory API. Both interfaces were discontinued in Workstation 6.5."

So it seems now you can only use the vmci SOCK_DGRAM or SOCK_STREAM sockets.  These behave much as tcp/ip sockets, and there is plenty of information on the net about how to write code that uses them, you basically just need the header vmci_sockets.h and off you go.

You will find the guest side of vsocket communication straightforward, however you need to write some kind of server to run on the ESXi host to host your DB, and this is the tricky part.  If you enable ssh on ESXi and have a sniff around, you will find a remarkably unix-like system with /dev/vsock device which you can query to get the vsocket protocol family (it may be different for your guests, you need to call the ioctl).  Unfortunately (and I tried this) simply compiling up a 64-bit statically linked Linux binary will get you nothing more than a segfault as the ESXi OS isn't sufficiently similar to Linux.

There is an SDK that you can try to use to create programs, however it's not for the faint hearted, some people have spent literally days just trying to get it to compile so you can try this route if you want, but I don't recommend it. Google for "VMWare ESXi toolchain".

However, if you are looking for a faster route to getting your own server running on ESXi, and are prepared to use Python you'll find both 5.5 and 6.0 come with a fairly up-to-date Python (Python 2.7.9 on ESXi v6.0).  VMWare unhelpfully removed the .py library files leaving just .pyc files so you can't easily see if this differs from the standard version, but it's certainly functional enough to get a basic socket server running.

The Python sockets module doesn't understand the vmci socket family, so you will need to use ctypes to bypass it calling the c library socket functions directly.  You can create the socket using pure python, even call listen() but e.g. bind() implicitly expects you to be dealing with sockaddr_in structures.

So you will need to inspect the vmci_sockets.h header, and come up with Python ctypes structures and functions to mirror the ones that you'd use from C, e.g.:

```
class sockaddr_vm(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("svm_family", c_ushort),
                ("svm_reserved1", c_ushort),
                ("svm_port", c_uint),
                ("svm_cid", c_uint),
                ("svm_zero", c_uint),
               ]
```

This can then be passed into the libc bind/recvfrom/sendto calls which you can access with:

```
libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
```

And you can then bind to your socket bypassing Pythons socket module, i.e.

```
addr = sockaddr_vm()
addr.svm_family = af     # address family obtained from ioctl
addr.svm_reserved1 = 0
addr.svm_cid = VMADDR_CID_ANY    # 0xffffffff
addr.svm_port = port
addr.svm_zero = 0

# s is the socket, created with python socket.socket()
out = libc.bind(s.fileno(), pointer(addr), sizeof(addr))
```

One caveat of Python on ESXi is that you seem to be limited in the memory you can play with:  I tried allocating a 16MB buffer and Python refused to give it to me with memory error, however this wasn't a problem for what I was doing at the time so I didn't bother trying to find a way around it.  I suspect there's a setting that can fix that.

Getting your script started at ESXi boot time is left as an exercise for the reader but this should get you started.  Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

VMCI is what you would require. Unfortunately, VMCI is deprecated between VMs from vSphere 6 and above.